# A syntax error is received when using wildcard characters with conman and composer on a Workload Scheduler dynamic agent installed on IBM i

Tags: command-line, syntax-error, workload-scheduler

A syntax error is received when using @ and # wildcard characters with **conman** and **composer** command lines on a Workload Scheduler dynamic agent installed on IBM i. It seems like the wildcard characters @ ad # are misunderstood by the server that considers them as the object full name.
See the following examples:

```
> li js      
  S_MDM#JS_RERSUCC_EXT1                                                  
      ¢                                                                     
  AWSBHW007E There is a syntax error. The job stream name must be
  between 1 and 16 bytes.

> li js   
  S_MDM#JS                                                               
  AWSBIA291I Total objects: 
  0                                                  

conman listsucc S_MDM#JS_RERSUCC_IBMI(1143 
05/21).JOB_RERSUCC_IBMI1  
        ¢                                                                   
AWSBHU744E There is a syntax error. The job stream name must be 
between 1 and 16 bytes.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to a wrong codepage setting on the client connected to the server. 
Change the codepage setting on the client and retry.